# Building an MO app?

Tags: discussion

On [stackapps](https://stackapps.com/), there is a broad spectrum of apps designed by users to improve their Stack Exchange experience. Most apps are oriented toward Stack Oveflow and do not necessarily address the needs and desires of the MathOverflow community. There are many reasons for this, the most obvious is that Stack Overflow has plenty of users that are avid coders. Some of our users are experienced and avid coders, so there is a definite possibility to have MO apps. Are we ready to get started?

Building a first MO app might help others to see more possibilities and create more MO apps. Moreover, having one MO app with reusable MO specific code will reduce the workload for later MO apps. Check out [stackapps](https://stackapps.com/) and the [SE 2.1 API](https://api.stackexchange.com/) to see what is possible.

- What would you want this first MO app to do?
- Would you volunteer for such a coding project?

Comment: I would like it to block all answers like "I should add more detail here but I am on my iPad and I have no real keyboard, so this quick one-liner will do".

Answer (score 7):

I would like the app to list the questions in some orders (by edit time,  type, or some other ranking) with abbreviated but expandable fields.  In particular, I want to know if there was just a comment added, or an 
edit of more than or fewer than 10 characters to either question or answer.  I might even want it to poll my favorites and show edits on just those.

I could tweak code if there was a good base.  I'm not prepared to write one from scratch.

Comment: Your last comment emphasizes the need for a first MO app...

Answer (score 4):

I use the StackExchange app, and I would like something similar which renders MathJax in question titles.  That would create the MO app that I want.

Here is what I see now in the StackExhange app:  [image: current questions in app]

Comment: If I am not mistaken, this answer is totally unrelated to Francois Dorais's question (The question is about completely different type of app.) Moreover, I think that meta.SE might be a better place for your inquiry and it might have already been addressed there. For example, this post seems closely related: [Please add TeX rendering in titles on the iOS app](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231730/please-add-tex-rendering-in-titles-on-the-ios-app)

Comment: @MartinSleziak I've clarified.

Comment: That looks like an iPhone interface. You might want to add some basic technical details (e.g. iPhone or Android, or phone model, and which operating system version you're using).